# How do I declare a variable of a generic type without knowing the type arguments?

Tags: delphi, generics, type-erasure

How do I define a generic `TList` type so that I can declare a variable of that type and then assign any specialization of `TList<>` to it?

I want to declare this variable:

```
var
  MyList:THowToDeclareThisListType<T>;
```

And then instantiate it like this:

```
MyList:=THowToDeclareThisListType<integer>.Create;
```

or

```
MyList:=THowToDeclareThisListType<double>.Create;
```

etc. I must be missing something pretty obvious here. I don't want classes, just a simple type definition.

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish?  What do you need your list for?  Do you want to create a list with added functionality, based on a generic `TList<T>`?  Or do you want to create a list of objects of a specific type?

Comment: I want to declare a TList<T> that will hold the list of integers, or strings or doubles. Not sure how to declare this.

Comment: do you mean a TList that will hold integers, strings AND doubles at the same time?  If so, you’ll have to use a `TList<Variant>` (if Delphi supports that).  Otherwise, it’s simple: just replace the `T` in the type declaration by the type you want to put in your list.

Comment: I was hoping to declare a Class something like
type TMyList = TList<T> and then instantiate it like integers or strings but as David said, type must be fully instantiated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to declare a variable like this:

```
var
  List: TList<?>;
```

such that `List` can be assigned objects of type `TList<Integer>` or `TList<Double>` or `TList<string>`.

That is not possible. When you define a variable using a generic type, the type must be fully instantiated.

The only way that you can have a variable that holds any object of type `TList<T>` is if the variable is declared to have a common base class to `TList<T>`. And the common base class cannot be a non-instantiated generic. For `TList<T>` the only possible common base class is `TObject`.

So you could write

```
var
  List: TObject;
```

and then assign any of your objects to `List`. But I'm not sure that would be terribly useful!

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks.